# Displaying a list of contacts in a form and allowing the user to add new ones

Tags: angular

SOLVED: thanks to @Gourav - I just needed to add the data into my form like this:

```
buildFormDynamic(item: Item): FormGroup {
return this.fb.group({
  data: [item && item.data],
});
```

}

UPDATE: The form builder code appears correct; however, the problem seems to be that the json data isn't getting populated correctly when it first loads.

UPDATE: I'm using Angular 8 and I'm now dynamically creating my form using this mock JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "item": [
      {
        "data": "object property"
      },
      {
        "data": "object property 2",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The idea is that the form will show a contact section for all the items returned; in this case 3. Here's how I dynamically build it:

```
private service: ItemService;
private items: Array;
itemForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private service: ItemService) 
{
  this.service = service;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.items = this.service.getItems();
  this.createForm();
}

createForm() {
  let arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < this.items.data.item.length; i++) {
    arr.push(this.buildFormDynamic(this.items.data.item[i]));
  }

  this.itemForm = this.fb.group({
    itemDetails: this.fb.array(arr)
  });
}

buildFormDynamic(contact: Object): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    data: [""],
    itemId: [""]
  });
}
```

And here's my updated HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="itemForm" >
  <div>
    <div>
      <input formControlName="isItem" type="radio" name="item" />
      <input formControlName="isNotItem" type="radio" name="item" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div formArrayName="itemDetails"
      *ngFor="
        let contact of itemForm.controls.items.controls[i]
          .controls;
        let i = index
      ">
    <div formGroupName="{{ i }}">
    <div>
      <input formControlName="name" type="text" id="itemName" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <input formControlName="itemId" type="text" id="itemId" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">
        Add an Item
      </button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="button">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button">Save</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm not getting any errors with paths to my controls. And when I check to see if my stuff is here where I expect it:

```
let item of itemForm.controls.items.controls[i]
          .controls;
```

...it appears to be the correct path. But I'm still getting the error that "controls are undefined". Is this not the right way to do this? My FB array has 3 form groups.

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<form [formGroup]="clientProfileForm">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input formControlName="isAdmin" type="radio" name="admin" />
      <input formControlName="isNotAdmin" type="radio" name="admin" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div formArrayName="contactDetails" *ngFor="
        let contact of clientProfileForm.controls.contactDetails.controls; let i = index
      ">
    <div formGroupName="{{ i }}">
      <div>
        <input formControlName="name" type="text" id="fullName" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input formControlName="phone" type="number" />
        <input formControlName="phoneExt" type="number" id="phoneExt" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input formControlName="email" type="text" id="email" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input formControlName="implementationRole" type="checkbox" name="implementationRole" />

      <input formControlName="operationsRole" type="checkbox" name="operationsRole" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <input formControlName="userId" type="text" id="userId" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="addContact()">
        Add a contact
      </button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="button">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want to access this form array in html, you should not use functions in interpolations as it can kill your application performance due to continuously calling function.

[Functions in interpolation](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16)

```
let contact of clientProfileForm.controls.contactDetails.controls
```

You can simply use in html, which will not cause any issue.

This will run loop over the 3 formgroups and assign the value to controls.

```
<div *ngFor="
    let contact of clientProfileForm.controls.contactDetails.controls; let i = index
  ">
<div formGroupName="{{ i }}">
  <div>
    <input formControlName="name" type="text" id="fullName" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input formControlName="phone" type="number" />
    <input formControlName="phoneExt" type="number" id="phoneExt" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input formControlName="email" type="text" id="email" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I commented on the post above but the point is that what you wrote -- clientProfileForm.controls.contactDetails.controls -- returns an array of 3 form groups. The data I need to show in the form is in each form group > controls. How can I access that?

Comment: This should display the desired value in your forms.

Comment: I like this approach better, using the html - thank you. But the code that references the controls is essentially the same. It's still not working. This -- clientProfileForm.controls.contactDetails.controls -- returns an array of 3 form groups with their own controls. Are you saying that "contact" should give me access to those controls? I don't believe that's the case.

Comment: Yes, contact will behave as formGroup now and will provide information of internal controls

Comment: Ok, I believe that because I'm not getting any errors about "controls" being undefined when I load the page. However, for some reason, it's still not showing up. Let me get to the bottom of it asap so I can give you the bounty. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my post. The problem seems to be that the json data that I'm loading isn't getting into the form. Even though the form is getting created 3 times the data isn't getting in there.

Comment: It won’t let me donut for another hour.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see the problem.
I faced with a similar problem wihle working with dynamic forms using form array.

You need to modify your 'clientProfileForm.controls' in your template.

Add the below function in your component ts file.

```
    getContactControls() {
        return (this.clientProfileForm.get('contactDetails') as FormArray).controls;
    }
```

then modify your template file as below.

```
    <div formArrayName="contactDetails" *ngFor="let contact of getContactControls(); let i = index">
        ...
    </div>
```

Here is a working [Stakblitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tk6p2s).

Comment: I appreciate the response but it's still not working. My data is not in this.clientProfileForm.get('contactDetails') as FormArray).controls. What you wrote will return an array of 3 form groups, each representing one instance of the form. The data that I need is in each form group.controls.